# How to Add youtube videos into webpage

Tags: html

I want to add a video into my website.

```
 <p><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChgO7gy5HjRQXuj9hMJQXkw/playlists"></iframe></p>
```

After Using the above code the video is not coming up. Please what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check your browser's developer tools, you'll see the following error:

> Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChgO7gy5HjRQXuj9hMJQXkw/playlists' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

You can't embed YouTube in an iframe like that.  You have to use one of their embeddable widgets.

See also:  https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en

Comment: Thanks, Brad. followed your guide it was indeed helpful.